# Creating movie from still images in Android?

Tags: android

My requirement is to create movie from still images. I tried to create animation using these images and got success in that but that is not my requirement. I want to create a movie and need to save it in some format like .mp4 or .3gpp. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you heard of the gif file format?

Comment: yes.but i need to create .mp4 format file with the images i captured from camera.

Comment: That was an answer to your "any alternative option" . If you have to create an mp4 you can [use ffmpeg](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android make animated video from list of images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images)